# c# finding text rtb using richtextbox.Find and using as check

Tags: c#, text, find

Hi can someone please show me correct syntax I wont to find word "Core" run some code else find word "Business" run some code in richtexbox.

So my richtextbox will have text like c:\core\app1\ver\name

```
 {
            string core = "Core";
            string business = "Business";

           if  richTextBox2.Find(core);
            {
                MessageBox.Show ("Found Core");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show ("Found Business");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text property of the richtextbox:

```
if(richTextBox2.Text.Contains("Core"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found Core");
}
if(richTextBox2.Text.Contains("Business"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found Business");
}
```

You can use "else if" but the above will alert you if your richtextbox contains core, business or both.